# How to convert array of numbers inside a string to integer array in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an array like `["1,2,3,"]`. I am trying to convert the numbers inside this array to a pure integer array like `[1,2,3]`. How to do that?

I tried using `string_to_array(cast(('2,3,') as VARCHAR))`, But this function expects input to be STRING. I tried casting to varchar and text, But it is not working.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here;  please [edit] your question to retag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Answer (score 0):

`string_to_array` splits string into array elements using supplied delimiter and optional null string.

In your case we need to make your string a valid comma separated string, to do so we need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to make it clean :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '\["|,?"\]', '', 'g')
```

So your query can be :

```
select *, REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '\["|,?"\]', '', 'g'), string_to_array(REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '\["|,?"\]', '', 'g'), ',')
from mytable;
```

Result :

```
mycolumn    regexp_replace  string_to_array
["1,2,3,"]  1,2,3           {1,2,3}
["2,3"]     2,3             {2,3}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/m9C5-_mA)